# How to change/toggle class of a div on click a button in angular 6

Tags: html, angular

Here I have a **div** having class name is `old`. I have a button also **onchange/toggle** of the button I need to change the **div's** class name to `new`.Again click on to button I need to change the class of div to .so on.. in angular 6. Here is the code below,

Actually I new in angular 6 can anyone please help me.

### app.component.html

```
<button (click)="change()">change</button>
<div class="old">
  Hello
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  change(){
    alert('change');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a boolean variable and [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive.

**Template:**

```
<button (click)="change()">change</button>
<div [ngClass]="{'old': toggle, 'new': !toggle}"class="old">
  Hello
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  toggle:boolean = true;


  change(){
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ju2c9t)